# How do I filter a model in html django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to filter a model in HTML I know that you can use eg. Model.objects.filter(bla=bloo, ...).
I wanna do that in HTML not in my views.py.
my model looks like this:

```
class Like(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likeUser")
post = models.ForeignKey(NewPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

heres my views.py:

```
posts = NewPost.objects.all()
like = Like
return render(request, "network/index.html", {
      "posts": posts,
      "like": like
)}
```

heres what I'm trying to do in HTML:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ like.objects.filter(post=post) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting an error right now saying: **Could not parse the remainder: '(post=post)' from 'like.objects.filter(post=post)'**
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), a reverse relation is created by default, so you can simply do:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.like_set }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's awesome, never knew that existed. Thanks!!